# how to select specific element id from dynamic element ids and pass it as function arguments - javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, dom

Upon `onclick` function other variables pass to another function perfectly but when checking the `val()` of specific Input field value it gives `undefined`. I might be wrong it following way

1. maybe I am  not getting the input text field id correctly
2. No proper way of making the input element id dynamic
3. element id is not escaping properly

Here is my code

```
`function addVariable(data, index) {
  

        var datavar = {

            itemname : data[index].name,
            itemprice : data[index].price,
            itemtotal : data[index].price,
            itemcounter :  data[index].id,
          };

        addRow(datavar);  // creates table and display data + input field 

       }`


function addRow(datavar){

            var inputvalue= 'inputid'+ datavar.itemcounter;
            var btn ="<input type='button' onclick='addbill("+datavar.itemprice+","+datavar.itemcounter+",\""+inputvalue+"\");'  value='add item' />";

         var $table =$('#product_list tbody');
         var $row  =
                    $(
                      " <tr id='parent "+datavar.itemcounter + " '>" +
                      "<td id='price "+datavar.itemcounter + " '>" + datavar.itemname +    "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + datavar.itemprice +    "</td>" +
                        "<td >  <input type='text' id='"+inputvalue+" '   name='"+inputvalue+"'     min='1'  >     </td>" +

                        
                        "<td>" + btn + "</td>" +
                      
                        "</tr>"
                    );

                    $row.data("itemname",datavar.itemname);
                    $row.data("itemnprice",datavar.itemprice);
                    $row.data("itemntotal",datavar.itemtotal);
                    $row.data("itemntotal",datavar.itemcounter);
                    $row.data("quantity",inputy);

                  total += Number(datavar.itemprice );
                  $('#finaltotal').val(total);

                  $table.append($row);

                }

`function addbill(itemprice,itemid,inputvalue){

              var t =   document.getElementById(inputvalue).value; // gives undefined in console.log

             //  var t  = $('#' + inputvalue).val();  // same issue as above 

             //  var t  =  $('#product_list tbody').find('input').val(); // gets first row input value
}
```

`

upon checking directly as `console.log(inputvalue)` it gives dynamic id such as inputvalue1 ,inputvalue2, as their respective loop value but I am not able to get the value of input field upon using `val()` or `value`

Comment: Your input's ids is `'q'+ datavar.itemcounter`, but you trying to get it by `quantity `. May be it is a problem?

Comment: @vbykovsky I apologise having you hard time to understand my code , I edit it now for better understanding